# Firebirdclient and Select statements are slow for no reason

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5, firebird-.net-provider

I have a .Net 4.6.1 Winforms application which has more or less 10 years.
It has worked pretty well since the beginning, but in the last few weeks I faced a problem I never had.

- Firebird 2.5 (latest version available)
- .net client (latest version available)
- Visual studio 2015 or 2019 (in both versions, same problem)

Now, the application, when is about Firebird, calls a sequence of select statements in order to load a dataset. It works well, as usual, as it always worked. Since few weeks, the whole sequence of select statements is slow, tremendously slow.

What do I mean with slow? It usually takes 5 or 6 seconds in my PC to load the whole set of data, now it takes 70 seconds, with no reason. Nothing has changed in the architecture or sequence, nothing was added or removed from the environment.

However, I don't know why, the **release** version of the software is fast as it was originally, so I don't really get where the point is here.
I have a **debug** version in Visual Studio which is slow at loading the data using a set of select statements, and a release version which is fast as usual.

Now, when I first realized that the software was running very slow, I upgraded the whole set of Firebird components to the latest versions, but had no joy. I was still using old versions because I had no real reason to upgrade: "does it work? Don't touch it!"

In the release version I use the embedded Firebird version, because I have to redistribute the application. In the debug, the server version, so I can manage the database with IBExpert and run the software together. It has always been like this since ages.

So, I'm looking for a suggestion, because I have no idea where or what to look for.

Comment: This sounds like a question that would be more suitable for either the [firebird-net-provider](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-net-provider) or the [firebird-support](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support) Google Group. Stack Overflow is not really suitable for troubleshooting questions like this. In any case, I would recommend you check the gstat statistics of the database used with your debug version, and maybe try if a backup and restore resolves the performance problem.

Comment: You have to try and remove uncertainties. Assuming the database file is one and the same for both apps, an obvious test for example would be running release app with the standalone server and ibexpert session open, and running debug app with the embedded server and then check which one goes slow. That way, step by step, you may narow down the problem to the unknown yet triggering factor.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this odd behaviour by setting *Pooling=true* in the connection properties